# How many squares can you find in the picture?

Tags: pattern, pencil-and-paper-games

How many sqares can you draw in given pattern, when each corner of a sqare has to lie in the exact center of one of the 20 colored circles?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are an infinite number of squares whose sides pass through exactly four circles. In fact, there are an infinite number of squares passing through the top four circles alone.

[image]

Each frame of the above gif represents one possible square you can draw through those circles. In addition to the 90 squares represented in these 90 frames, there are infinitely many more. For example, "the square that lies halfway between frame 1 and frame 2".

---

Edit: If we add the additional constraint that the *corners* of the square must lie on a circle, then there are 17, as originally determined by kaine.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that this answer applies to "how many squares are there whose lines pass through these circles?", but not "how many squares are there whose _corners_ lie on these circles?". I wasn't sure how to interpret the question, so I went with the former.

Comment: wrong answer, it seems you didn't get the question,look at kaine's answer.

Comment: @Riddle, What's wrong with it? All of my squares satisfy the criteria "your square shouldn't have more than 4 or less than 4 circles. and your lines should pass the 4 circles." Please clarify your question.

Comment: your edit is perfect seems best answer for me till now.

Comment: you can delete the infinite answer, and keep the edited part, it's just what i meant in the question.

Comment: +1. The infinite answer should be kept. That is the reason how people should formulate their question very precisely :)

Comment: Even with "The Corners lie on four circles" you still have infinite squares by tilting and moving. The question should be "Which corners are at the exact centers of one of the 20 colored circles"

Answer (score 14):

9 squares that are $1$x$1$     (trivial)

4 squares that are $\sqrt{2}$x$\sqrt{2}$ (Diamonds centered at the 4 central circles)

2 squares that are $\sqrt{5}$x$\sqrt{5}$ (Each starts at a yellow circle. Move like a knight: example 2 right 1 up, 2 up 1 left, 2 left 1 down, 2 down 1 right)

2 squares that are $\sqrt{13}$x$\sqrt{13}$ (Each starts at the orange circles. Move 3 right 2 up or 3 left 2 up and then keep going)

Are there more than that?

Comment: I can only see nine $1 \times 1$ squares. There are also four $\sqrt{8} \times \sqrt{8}$ squares

Comment: Thank you, miscounted.  Don't the $\sqrt 8$ squares go through additional circles? 8 is made from 2 square numbers by 4+4 and the 4 squares with those dimensions I found go through 3 more circles each.

Comment: can you show √5 and √13 in picture?

Comment: @kaine According to the current wording of the puzzle there is nothing wrong with the squares intersecting additional circles.

Answer (score 8):

I found 21

- 9 variations of black square
- 2 variations of orange square
- 4 variations of brown square
- 4 variations of gray square
- 2 variations of red square

[image]

Comment: actually, i told in question that each square must be exactly on 4 circles ,but one of your square is on 8 circles, but my question was edited. so your answer is correct, but other answeres are correct too, because they answered before the edit happens.

Answer (score 6):

My answer is 21. It break down as follows:

9: Square from dots right next to each other

4: Squares with 1 dot in the middle

2: Squares with central 4 dots in the middle

2: Squares with previous 2 squares in the middle
(The above can be more easily visualized from watching Kevin's answer)

4: From the 4 squares with 1 dot in the middle, extend out 1 more dot on each corner to make another square.

The total of 9 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 21.

Comment: Given the recent change to the question, this answer appears to be the most correct now (addition of 4 squares that previously were considered incorrect).

Answer (score 3):

I have found 21 Squares, too.

As [Kevin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1497/kevin) illustrated in his [beautiful answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/how-many-squares-can-you-find-in-the-pattern/2125#answer-2082) there are 17 squares. PLUS there are 4 more squares.

all the squares are as follows:

Dimensions  How many

- Nine × [1x1]
- Four × [√2×√2]
- Two × [√5×√5]
- Four × [√8×√8]
- Two × [√13×√13]
- TOTAL of 21 squares